# Preventing ScrollView from scrolling in certain area?

Tags: iphone, scrollview, swipe

I hope you can help me...

I have a scrollview (UIScrollview) that contains a contentView (UiView).

Inside the contentview I have a Horizontal slider. My problem is that if the user swipes just next to the slider, trying to hit the slider, the scrollview scrolls. I would like to enlarge the area of the slider if possible, or just disable scrolling for a certain part of the scroll view.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the following properties for customizing the look of a scroll view:

```
indicatorStyle
scrollIndicatorInsets
```

Or if this isn't to your taste: You could subclass UIScrollView and when the custom slider receives touches, read them in transform them and call setContentOffset on the UIScrollView. In my opinion that seems like a big task for very little reward and I'd just stick with the default behaviour/look.

Comment: I do not want to customize the look of the scrollview but the action of it. It is when the user doesn't hit the slider but right next to it, in the scroll view...